# Adding parent type in elasticsearch index without updating its existing docs

Tags: elasticsearch, join, parent-child, aws-elasticsearch

I am in the process of upgrading the version of existing ElasticSearch cluster (5.x) to 6.x to achieve the parent-child relationship. I have some parent index where I want to add the new join type in its mapping so that I can have the parent child relation with the child index.

Parent Mapping:

```
{
     "properties": {
      "my_join_field": { 
        "type": "join",
        "relations": {
          "parent": ["child"] 
        }
      }
    }  
}
```

I can add the new join type to the parent mapping by using the _mapping API however I need to update each existing doc in that index to have the new join attribute. We have nearly a billion data in this index and we do not want to update each doc to have the new relationship.

Is there a way to handle this effectively? Is there an alternate workaround to achieve the same without touching the docs?

Thanks for your guidance !!!